# How to group by and order by using 2 different id

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone I have a table that has user_id and auto increment Id

```
user_id|points|id
  3432 |400   |1
  3431 |99    |2
  3333 |340   |3
  4671 |34    |4
  9911 |700   |5
  3432 |100   |6
  3333 |841   |7
```

My goal is to create the sql that will order the user_id based on the higher points but taking in consideration of the last auto incremented Id of that user_id.I need my output to be like this

```
 user_id|points
 3333   |841
 9911   |700
 3432   |100
 3431   |99
 4671   |34
```

but a the moment it only pick user_id and its first points meaning instead of

```
    3432 |100
```

is doing 
        3432 |400

CHECK MYSQL below

```
 SELECT * From points_table where points < 3000 GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY  points DESC.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want the last record and then to sort them.  Here is one way:

```
select pt.*
from points_table pt
where pt.id = (select max(pt2.id) from points_table pt2 where pt2.user_id = pt.user_id)
order by pt.points desc;
```